# How can I trigger error object in lambda.invoke

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How can i trigger error object in lambda.invoke

```
lambda.invoke(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(.... // I would have expected below error to show up here
  else
    // error shows up inside the data.Payload
    const result = data.Payload
    // I have to create a condition to check for the error
    resolve(result);
```

in the called lambda, i've tried the following:

```
exports.handler = ( event, context, callback) => {

  if (payload === '')
    context.done(new Error('my error message');

}
```

however, the error object ends up in the payload, where I have to check for it instead of going into a catch or other error path.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the "older way" to stop execution you should use the `callback(error, [success])` method.  So in your lambda being invoked try `callback('my error message')` and that should go into your if block.  You can read the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html) for more info.  I believe that in the "older way" of doing things `context.done()` is considered successful and `context.fail()` was used to signify an error.